# What do you call a subset of a collection?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I get confused with this. A set, is a collection of *distinct* objects. But what if I have a collection that contains duplicates but I need to check if another collection have items that matches all items in the other collect. Can I still call it as subset?

Example:

A = [1,2,2,3,3,3];

B = [1,2]; B ⊆ A = true

C = [1,2,2] C ⊆ A = true

D = [1,1,2]; D ⊆ A = *still true*

Basically, if I considered A as a set, then B, C and D are subset of A. But if I counted the duplicates, then can I consider D as not a *part* of A? What term should I use instead of *set* and *subset*?

In this scenario, what principle/theory should I use to check matches between two collections if I want to consider the number of the duplicates as part of criteria? In my example, would make the case D as *false*

Comment: If you want to take into account multiplicity, you have to use [multisets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset) : "a modification of the concept of a set that, unlike a set, allows for multiple instances for each of its elements."

Comment: In that case, $D$ is not *included* into $A$ because the multiplicity of the element $1$ is $D$ (call it $m_D(1)$) is greater then its multiplicity in $A$, i.e. $m_D(1) > m_A(1)$.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA exactly what I'm looking for! thank you very much

Comment: You are welcome :-)